# C++ Random Number

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I created a random number generator (between 100 and 1) for an Array but each time I run it it outputs the same 10 numbers between 1 and 100.

```
for (int x=0; x < 10; x++) {
       arr[x]=rand() % 100 + 1;
```

The Loop runs 10 times because the array contains 10 integers. Every time I run this though, it outputs: 42, 68, 35, 1, 70, 25, 79, 59, 63, 65.

It Outputs from this line of code

```
 for (int z=0; z<10;z++) {
       cout << arr[z]<<", ";
 }
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: Your program uses the same seed each time.

Comment: Are you calling `srand` at any point?

Comment: "Can anyone see why this is happening?" because you do not bother to read the documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: I'll just leave these links here (*please* don't use `(s)rand` in new/modern code) : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random , https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @Slava cplusplus.com is a pretty poor quality reference. Prefer cppreference.com ..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but `rand()` is not a good quality function, so I think this is fine.

Comment: random_gen() % some_num + 1 is an "anti-pattern"

Answer (score 0):

When using `rand()` it will generate the same sequence from the given input to `srand()`. Another words it will typically use the same generated numbers from the initial seed value. These functions are considered to be frowned upon in their use and some even want them to be marked as `deprecated` in favor of the modern `std` pseudo-random number generators library.

To generate random numbers try using the library from the `<random>` header instead.

You can find the documentations here: [cppreference::random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: The first sentence is less than clear - by design, `rand` will always generate the same sequence, given a particular input to `srand`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth true; I was just trying to stress on the better use of the `<random>` library.